# Swift | UIButton causes crash on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, presentviewcontroller

I added a button on the main screen of the app and on the tap of a button, a new `viewcontroller` is presented.
This works completely fine in the simulator but as soon as I try in an actual iPhone, it causes the app to crash.

Also, the crash is only caused on the login button while the sign up button made the same way does work perfect

I will leave the code below

```
 var loginButton = UIButton()
var signUpButton = UIButton()

 loginButton.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
    loginButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    loginButton.backgroundColor = appGreenTheme
    loginButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    loginButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    loginButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pinkOrangeGradientPDF"), for: .normal)
    loginButton.clipsToBounds = true


    signUpButton.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
    signUpButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    signUpButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    signUpButton.backgroundColor = .white
    signUpButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .black
    signUpButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    signUpButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)


    loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginButtonTapped1(_:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

    signUpButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signUpButtonTapped1(_:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

   @objc func loginButtonTapped1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func signUpButtonTapped1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SignUpViewController())
    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I also tried with "touchUpInside" events. again it works perfectly in the simulator but not in a physical device.

Any help is welcome.

Below is the error shown in the logs

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SparkGPS.LoginView addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13dd4c740'
```

Comment: What do logs tell you?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SparkGPS.LoginView addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111d49220'

Comment: i tried google but this does not seem to go away from generic fixes

Comment: Given you don't need the information on the button in your action methods, have you tried to change their signature to `loginButtonTapped()` and `signUpButtonTapped()` and change the selectors to `#selector(loginButtonTapped)`and `#selector(signUpButtonTapped)` ?

Comment: yes i did, it still crashes with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error message. Somewhere, my guess is in `LoginViewController`, there is a view of type `LoginView`. That view is calling `addTarget(_:action:for:)`. `LoginView` is not subclassed from `UIControl` and does not have `addTarget(_:action:for:)`. It's causing the crash.

Let me break down the parts of `-[SparkGPS.LoginView addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]`.

- The `-` at the beginning means it's an instance method and not a static or class method.
- `SparkGPS.LoginView` is the module and class. A module is another word for a framework or app. In this case, it looks like you have an app named `SparkGPS` and a class named `LoginView`.
- `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` is Objective-C's name for `addTarget(_:action:for:)`.

Finally, "selector sent to instance" means the variable call a method. Selector is a way to identify a method, and an instance is stored in a variable. For example, in your code you have `loginButton.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)`. This could be worded as `setTitle(_:for:)` was sent to the instance `loginButton`.

Comment: the thing is i have already done this a few times and it works the same way, i also tried renaming the button from both views and their target so they dont collide and yet same issue, can you suggest a solution?

Comment: it gave me a hint but still no clue, i went to login view and commented that login button add target that you mentioned and when i uncommented it, started working out of nowhere without any changes, quite wierd, thanks for the answer, did help a lot but i dont know if this is what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tap gesture recogniser to the button itself. It's best practice to use outlets, but this works fine and is useful for other UI components like views or labels too

```
let loginTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                 action: #selector(loginButtonTapped1))
loginButton.addGestureRecognizer(loginTapGesture)
```

Comment: i tried and it still crashed the same way with the same error and the sign up button which is made the same way works absolutely fine as it is

Comment: My guess is that `self` isn't the same object that the selector is on. They should both be on the same object